# R dplyr heatmap dealing with missing values

Tags: r, dplyr, heatmap

so I have run into a minor issue with drawing heat maps using geom_tile() and dplyr package. I assume that it is a simple solution, but I have not been able to find the answer anywhere yet. Apologies if there is one out there and I just missed it.

So the following code is for a trivial example:

```
Trivial <- tibble(
  Name1 = c("a","b","c"),
  Name2 = c("x","y","z"),
  Value = c(1,2,3)
)
Trivial %>%
  ggplot(aes(Name1, Name2)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = Value)) +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "green")
```

The heat map produced by this shows grey/blank space where there is no information for those combinations of Name1 and Name2. Is there a way of instead of showing blank space I could fill it with white (or any other colour)? Alternatively, could I put a "NA" on the plot to show that those blank spaces are indeed meant to be blank?

I have tried using the na.value argument in scale_fill_gradient, but it does not work. I assume since there are no NAs in the table. However, I think that could be a way forward. I will keep experimenting, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `expand()` from `tidyr` to get all combinations of `Name1` and `Name2` and then fill all `NA` with `0` and then plot the heatmap:

```
library(tidyr)      
Trivial %>% expand(Name1, Name2) %>% 
  left_join(Trivial, by = c("Name1", "Name2")) %>%
  mutate( Value = ifelse(is.na(Value), 0, Value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Name1, Name2)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "green")
```

The result looks like this:

[image: output]

Comment: Any idea how this would scale with many thousands of combinations?

Comment: It would scale ok-ish, I guess a much more efficient way of doing it is the answer that George has provided.

Comment: Yeah both answers work, I am just trying to figure out which one would be best to implement in my real scenario...

Comment: I prefer this solution, so will implement it for now. However if scalability proves to be an issue I may need to revisit. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Or you can just add `them_classic()`.

```
Trivial %>%
    ggplot(aes(Name1, Name2)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = Value)) +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "gray", high = "green") + 
    theme_classic()
```

[image]

I just used `low= "gray"` because background is white.

You can change also the background :

```
Trivial %>%
    ggplot(aes(Name1, Name2)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = Value)) +
    scale_fill_gradient() + 
    theme_classic() +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"))
```

[image: image2]